# Poetry install not updating scripts

Tags: python, python-poetry

I made a simply change so that a script was moved up a directory. Poetry doesn't seem to recognize that it's been moved since the `poetry install` or `update` command does nothing

```
Installing dependencies from lock file

No dependencies to install or update
```

and the `poetry run script_name` command throws while referencing the old path.

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
launch = "launcher.launch:main"
```

Was the command. It reflected a directory structure `launcher/launch.py`, where a `Fire` CLI called `main`. This worked.

I moved `launch.py` up, removed the `launcher` directory, and updated poetry to

```
[tool.poetry.scripts]
launch = "launch:main"
```

But `poetry run launch` throws `No file/folder found for package launcher`

And again, `poetry install/update` does nothing.

What cache/meta data/etc do I need to delete to have poetry re-install things? I have also deleted the lock file and get the same behavior when running install.

Answer (score 0):

You most likely have to clear the cache, which you can do with

```
poetry cache clear --all .
```